# Can i add a workflow as an activity to another workflow?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation, composition

I would like to create compositions of workflows in WF (3.5). Is it possible to directly use a workflow as an activity inside another workflow? I don't want to use the InvokeWorkFlowActivity, since it executes the workflow asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late follow up: found out later that you can use workflows by dropping them in from your toolbox (Doh!)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog: [CallWorkflowService](http://www.masteringbiztalk.com/blogs/jon/PermaLink,guid,7be9fb53-0ddf-4633-b358-01c3e9999088.aspx)

Taken in turn from this similar question: [loading-workflow-activity-dynamically-from-xoml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774258/loading-workflow-activity-dynamically-from-xoml)